# Couchbase update for multiple set

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the following `n1ql` query:

```
UPDATE default
USE KEYS '557a7628-1217-4974-95cf-d64247c560cd'
SET p.last_seen_message_id = 'e5010536-7fde-42c1-9fea-e4a29e560f53', p.last_seen_message_text = 'hello'
FOR p IN participants WHEN p.id = '119c35ab-a1cc-4e9f-bab5-d58d6d396623' END
WHERE doc_type = 'conversation'
RETURNING default.*
```

With this query, I would like to set two properties in an array's element, but only the last one (`p.last_seen_message_text = 'hello'`) has any effect. The first (in this case `p.last_seen_message_id = 'e5010536-7fde-42c1-9fea-e4a29e560f53'`) won't change the property.

I use Couchbase 4.5.1-2845 on Windows.

How could I solve this, without using two separate updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate **FOR** for each target.

```
UPDATE default
USE KEYS '557a7628-1217-4974-95cf-d64247c560cd'
SET p.last_seen_message_id = 'e5010536-7fde-42c1-9fea-e4a29e560f53' FOR p IN participants WHEN p.id = '119c35ab-a1cc-4e9f-bab5-d58d6d396623' END,
    p.last_seen_message_text = 'hello' FOR p IN participants WHEN p.id = '119c35ab-a1cc-4e9f-bab5-d58d6d396623' END
WHERE doc_type = 'conversation'
RETURNING default.*;
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.